# Postgres update with case causing error "could not determine data type of parameter $3"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an issue with our golang programs when querying sql statement as below.

"database/sql"

```
sqlStatement := `
    UPDATE user_posts SET
        content = $2,
        post_image = CASE WHEN ($3 IS NULL) THEN post_image ELSE $3 END,
        updated_at = NOW()
    WHERE id = $1
`
```

Comment: An alternative and shorter way to do the same: `post_image = COALESCE($3, post_image)`, if that breaks for the same or similar reason use a cast, i.e. `COALESCE($3, post_image)::<enter_type_of_post_image_column>`

Comment: that is true but I need to add record if $3 is not empty

Comment: You can combine `COALESCE` with `NULLIF` to handle both `NULL` and empty strings: `COALESCE(NULLIF($3, ''), post_image)`.

Comment: Btw what is the type of `post_image`? Is it `text`?

Comment: To fix your original query, I believe all you have to do is to add a cast to the `ELSE` unknown, i.e. `... ELSE $3::<type_of_post_image_column> ...`. https://postgresql.org/docs/13/interactive/typeconv-union-case.html

Answer (score 0):

Found the answers parameter $3 cannot compare with clause "IS NULL" fixed as below.

```
sqlStatement := `
    UPDATE user_posts SET
        content = $2,
        post_image = CASE WHEN $3 != '' THEN $3 ELSE post_image END,
        updated_at = NOW()
    WHERE id = $1
`
```

Comment: Note that this will not work if you pass in a Go `nil` value as the 3rd argument, unless, of course, storing `NULL` in the `post_image` column is legal per your requirements.